# Getting parent class's field from child class

Tags: php

Let's say I have two classes: SuperObject and PageGenerator.

PageGenerator (and a bunch of other classes) inherits SuperObject and SuperObject  has a field called 'db_conn' for database connections.

So my code looks something like:

```
class SuperObject {
    protected static $db_conn = null;
    public function __construct($db){ $this->db_conn = $db; }
}
class PageGenerator extends SuperObject {
     public function some_function(){
         //something using parent::$db_conn;
     }
 }
 // somewhere down the way
$so = new SuperObject( $db_object );
$page = new PageGenerator();
$page->some_function();
```

But I assume I can't do that, at least, not like that.

So what do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class SuperObject {
    protected static $db_conn = null;
    public function __construct($db){ self::$db_conn = $db; }
}
class PageGenerator extends SuperObject {
    public function some_function(){
        var_dump(self::$db_conn);
    }
}
// somewhere down the way
$page = new PageGenerator( new \stdClass() );
$page->some_function();
```

Comment: Huh. Wow, that worked. Are there any downsides to doing something like this?

Comment: Just, you have to keep in mind that static properties is class properties but not object. It means, value of static property will be changed for each class instance if you will change it in some instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parent protected static field:

```
public function some_function(){
     var_dump(self::$db_conn); //not parent::$db_conn;
}
```

but you not intialize it properly in SuperObject. Replace $this->db_conn with **self::$db_conn**:

```
class SuperObject {
    protected static $db_conn = null;
    public function __construct($db){ self::$db_conn = $db; }
}
```

Comment: But that would require me to call the parent's constructor function inside of the classes, which I want to avoid.